# Uniswap V1: Why does EthToTokenInput not refund overpaid ether?

Tags: exchanges, decentralized-exchange, defi

`ethToTokenInput` on the [Uniswap V1 contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v1/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_exchange.vy#L127) converts all the sent ether to tokens and transfers the tokens to the recipient.

Lets assume 1 ether buys you 3.9 tokens according to `getInputPrice()`. If you send 1 ether with `ethToTokenInput(1, ...)`, the contract will send you 3 tokens even though 3 tokens only cost rougly 0.8 ether.

- Why does this function not refund the remaining ~0.2 ether?
- Is the "overpaid" ether distributed among liquidity providers (added to the eth_reserves)?

Comment: In the function that you have linked, there is no indication of what you're saying. The only thing you "lose" is the non-integer part of token wei.

Comment: Yeah, what I am saying is that in this example it doesnt matter if I send 1 ether or 0.8 ether: I will get 3 tokens for it. My question is, why is there no refund implemented to refund the amount above the price for the floored token amount. If you use `ethToTokenOutput()` instead, there is such a refund mechanic implemented. I was wondering why for one function its there and for another its missing